# Why ISN'T `foo: 'bar'` a syntax error in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, syntax, ecmascript-6, ecmascript-5

A coworker of mine wrote the ES6 line of code...

`return map(orderedContentUuids, contentUuid => { uuid: contentUuid });`

As you can probably guess he intended to return the object `{uuid: contentUuid }`, but since its an arrow function, the curly brace `{` actually starts a new block. (The correct code would be `return map(orderedContentUuids, contentUuid => ({ uuid: contentUuid }));`).

But, unexpectedly, this code transpiles and runs without an error. There's no error because `uuid: contentUuid` seems to evaluate to `contentUuid`.

You can see then that if you put into your JavaScript console `foo: 'bar'` it evaluates to `"bar"`.

Huh? What's going on. Since when is that valid JS?

Answer (score 6):

Ooops. I just figured it out.

`foo: 'bar'` is evaluated as a "label", which I did not realize was a JavaScript feature.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/label

Comment: Indeed curly braces would not be considered an object in this context.